# Parsing large .txt files in Lua without tables

Tags: parsing, lua, lua-table

I'm reasonably new to Lua although I have used other languages which are similar. So far I've spent 8 hours to no avail trying to parse a large text file.

The file in question looks something like this: (but thousands of lines long)

```
A|KLAX|LOS ANGELES INTERNATIONAL|33942522|-118407161|125
```

I've got the user to enter the KLAX variable, but my goal is to get out this part of the line in question WITHOUT using tables:  `33942522|-118407161`

E.g.

```
APTDEP_DATA = 33942522|-118407161
```

Or even get a whole line out of the .txt file as a string?

E.g.

```
APTDEP_DATA = A|KLAX|LOS ANGELES INTERNATIONAL|33942522|-118407161|125
```

Thanks a heap in advance. After 8 hours, it would be great to know whether what I'm trying to do is even possible. (Every tutorial I see is parsing data into tables)

I've tried a lot of things to this effect:

[image]

THE NZAA is also a code I was trying to find. So don't get confused with KLAX thing. I was just trying to get a result.

(I couldn't get the code to show properly, sorry about the link)

Comment: Have you tried using `io.lines()`?

Comment: You spent 8 hours, and you didn't even think to [*read the documentation*](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-file:lines)?

Comment: Yes've tried using io.lines() and yes I did read the documentation... after 8 hours, you'd have to be an idiot not too...

Comment: It's not really clear to me what problem you're running into. Can you add more details on what you've tried and what exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: Trying to upload some of my code that didn't work, however i'm just having a bit of trouble making it appear correctly.

Comment: You know, there *is* a formatting help and even a button to format source code...

Comment: Also you are using a string operation (`string.match`) on a file pointer (`file`) - I don't see how tables are involved though.

Answer (score 4):

From looking at your example snippet, the problem is coming from your usage of:

```
AP_LAT = string.match(file, "A|NZAA")
```

Pattern matching is performed on a string value, *not* a `file` handle. More appropriate would be:

```
AP_LAT = string.match(line, "A|NZAA")
```

The following processes your input file a line at a time and also parses it to its respective fields:

```
file = assert(io.open("Airports.txt", "r"))

for line in file:lines() do
  local fields = { line:match "(%w+)|(%w+)|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)" }
  -- do something useful with it
  print(fields[4], fields[5])  -- the 2 numeric fields you're interested in
end

file:close()
```

If you're adamant about no tables, you can just punt the matches into variables like this:

```
local first, second, third, etc = line:match "(%w+)|(%w+)|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)"
```

Note: Feel free to modify/refine the pattern to suit your needs. This is just an example to illustrate the idea.

Comment: uh in this case it's really better to go without tables, it's a static structure and there is no reason for the table creation overhead.

Comment: Thank you! That is making it slow right down but that's because I'm running it once a frame. Atleast I know my computer is actually searching it. In your example, does the fields value have to be localised? Thanks again!

Comment: @user2609216 You can make `fields` global by removing `local` keyword but it's considered good coding practice to limit variable scope to where it's needed. For longer scripts, putting everything in global scope increases chance of name clash. You could accidentally override something you didn't mean to.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help, but it seems to be still not working say for instance I have this:

(%w+)|(%w+)|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)

but the second (%w+) needs to be searched can it be turned into:

"(%w+)|NZAA|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)"

Comment: @user2609216 what kind of lines is it failing to match?

Comment: @greatwolf Well I did put it in a table however, fields[4] is finding the number 8531. And I think that maybe be because the line match is trying to find w|w|w|d|d|d. (all the lines have that format). And when I try and put something like, w|(fourlettervalue)|w|d|d|d, it just reads out as 0. Is that what kind of lines you meant?

Comment: @user2609216 I mean what does the problematic line look like that you're matching. You said `fields[4]` has 8531 which I assume is incorrect. What should the correct match be?

Comment: @greatwolf Apologies for NZAA (auckland airport) the latitude is -37008056 (thats what 'im trying to find)

Comment: What does that whole line look like when reading from the file?

Comment: @greatwolf A|NZAA|AUCKLAND|-37008056|174791667|23

Comment: That's kind of strange, it should match. Can you print all the fields out and show what it looks like after each loop iteration? A previous line might be screwing things up. You can try adding `$` to the end of the pattern so it matches with a newline ending.

Comment: @greatwolf I essentially want the code to find the 4 digit code for the airport. If the user put in EGLL(same place in the line as NZAA), it would get the data for the line of Heathrow.

Comment: @greatwolf it just prints random characters that aren't even around the targetted line. But if I can't put the 4 digit code in, how is it knowing which line I want to find. Remember this Airports.txt file has many lines that follow the same pattern as the auckland NZAA line. Surely with the code in the example, its not actually searching for any particular line as there is no custom data added.

Comment: Can you add the code you currently have to your question? If you only want the pattern to match a user inputted code, you can concat that in the middle of the pattern. `"(%w+)|"..user_input.."|..."` etc.

Comment: Currently what is happening is I have all this code inside a function that gets called when one of the buttons gets clicked. I can tell its searching because as you click down it has to think for half or second or so. If do this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1510899/25-07-2013%2012-32-59%20a-m-.jpg , it just doesn't show anything. Also if I do this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1510899/25-07-2013%2012-34-03%20a-m-.jpg I get same result. I get a nil value.

Comment: @user2609216 Can you see if the following prints the fields out: http://pastebin.com/GrYtmnyT. Note that when you concat the code to the pattern, it isn't a capture group so the fields will be off by one. If you want the airport code captured also, be sure to surround it with `()`.

Comment: @user2609216 for efficiently, you might want to cache the processed table somewhere so you don't constantly reload it from file whenever you call `ap_lat`.

Comment: I copied that code in and still a nil. Im fresh out of idea's. what was thh ap_code you put in the function for?

Comment: @user2609216 Did you pass it the airport code eg. "NZAA" when you called it? I changed it to take an argument so you can specify the airport code it should look for.

Comment: I did. I can't think of any reason it doesn't work. If you think of anything else though, i'd love to know! Thanks.

Comment: For debugging, can you show what this code actually prints? http://pastebin.com/BgLRaq7Z

Comment: Unfortunately, print does not work in sim as it does not use any console i can see. You have to push to a value and draw the value as text. and even then it doesn't draw as nil. It just doesn't draw. When I did this, nothing showed up. Tomorrow, Im gonna make my own text file and just get it parse something basic. See if something screwy is happening on the plug-in level!

Comment: That must make debugging hard if you can't easily get feedback on output. My last idea is to check `field` actually isn't empty. Lines that doesn't match the airport code leads to an empty table. Maybe this might work http://pastebin.com/v9RPy27G.

Comment: @user2609216 why don't you write the script in an external file to run it with commandline Lua. Then you can debug it there, eliminate faults and finally integrate it into your program.

Comment: @greatwolf AHA! I figured something out. It is only reading the last line and through a series of tests, i've worked out that it is ignoring the rest of the .txt file. currently its only reading a runway in china which happens to be the very last line of the text file. 

If you have any ideas as to why its only reading the last line, I'd love to hear them. Thank you with bearing with me. I'm a bit of a newbie to parsing and I definately appreciate the help!

Comment: @user2609216 are you using `file:seek()` function anywhere? Do you have more than one file handle open to airport.txt somewhere else in your code?

Comment: No and I did a search through my code. Only one occurance of Airports.txt was found. could it be this part:

`for line in file:lines() do` thats causing it?

Comment: Doubtful, `file:lines()` returns a function iterator that returns the next line as a string. You're going to need some way to get feedback from the script or it'll be impossible to debug. Can you write a function that logs various outputs to say a file you can inspect?

Comment: You can use `file:seek()` to find out the current airport.txt position. For example, before entering loop, this should be true `assert(file:seek() == 0)`. After the loop, this should be true `local cur = file:seek(); assert(cur == file:seek("end"))`.

Comment: @greatwolf I've been working on adding file seek. I tried both what you put in and just a simple

`file:seek("set")`

Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To read lines from a file, use `io.lines`:

```
for line in io.lines(filename) do 
    --do some processing
end
```

To get specific part from the line, use pattern matching. I'm not sure what you are trying to get from the question.

Comment: I found the documentation on io.lines to be quite vague. Does io.lines just search an individual line or all lines? Also do you need the io.open in front. I was trying to pull any information I could and display it in the software (simulator) but nothing at all was being drawn from the:

APTDEP_DATA = string.match. I even tried the string.find. I think half my problem is I don't have any examples as no-one in any of the questions or tutorials is trying to get the information out, the way I have to. I see things like:

print and those commands don't work in sim.

Comment: @user2609216 `io.lines` process one line per time, that's why it's used with a `for` loop. Using `io.lines` doesn't need to open a file first, but using `file:lines` does.

Comment: Thank you, i'll be sure to try that.